# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de validar un email en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, regex

estoy tratando de hacer un formulario en [android](/questions/tagged/android) en el que uno de los campos es un **email** y quería saber si hay alguna forma de que compruebe automáticamente si el email introducido es correcto y sino que muestre algo parecido a lo que muestra la imagen siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El campo del **email** lo he especificado de la siguiente forma:

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/email"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="@color/letraAzul"
     android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
     android:textSize="@dimen/texto_letra"
     android:hint="Email"/>
```

donde `android:inputType="textEmailAddress"` sólo se encarga de mostrar un teclado para la introducción del email como dice la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html).

Si no hay una forma automática de hacer la comprobación, ¿Cúal sería la mejor forma de comprobar que sea  correcto el email?

Utilizar:

- `android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()`
- Una expresión regular del tipo `"^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$"` (¿qué expresión acepta más tipos de emails?)
- Otra forma

¿Alguien conoce cómo hacerlo o tiene algún ejemplo o documentación que me pueda servir?

Saludos

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Puedes usar la clase [Pattern](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```
  private boolean validarEmail(String email) {
    Pattern pattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
    return pattern.matcher(email).matches();
  }
```

Como puedes ver creamos un patrón EMAIL_ADDRESS y comprobamos con el método `matcher` si el email es correcto.

```
if (!validarEmail("miEmail@gmail.com")){
    miEditText.setError("Email no válido")
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, era una de las opciones que había tenido en cuenta, pero no sabía si sería la más correcta o eficaz

Answer (score 2):

Si solo quieres verificar que el email este bien formado, la clase `Pattern` es útil.

Si quieres saber si el email existe, es válido y no es un dirección disposable o ***spamtrap mail*** la única forma efectiva es utilizar un servicio externo para validar email. Hay bastantes proveedores, casi todos a través de una API con la que podrás hacer una llamada REST, y te devuelve el resultado de la validación del email.

```
//Llamada API validar email verificaremails.com
$email = "test@example.com";
$key = "your_api_key";
$url = "https://app.verificaremails.com/api/verifyEmail?secret=".$key."&email=".$email;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!